# 2 By 2 Responsive Table

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble making a responsive table that does the following. Using a media query it makes every table data (td) it own table row (tr).

Here each letter is a td. A and B are in a row and C and D are in a row.

```
-----
-A-B-
-C-D-
-----
```

Here each letter is a td. A, B, C and D are all on in a separate row.

```
-----
--A--
--B--
--C--
--D--
-----
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Let me google that for you: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

Just with media query, you can achieve this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px){
 table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pf21euep/